# Convert from string to datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a string that is passed from my code to SQL Server stored procedure:

```
select convert(datetime2, '08/03/20116 12:55:15')
```

It is throwing an error saying

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Do I need to convert the date to specific format like "-" instead of slash in order to get rid of conversion error

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the year has one too many '1's in it

Comment: You have wrong year 20116   try using 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example date is in incorrect format. It should be 2016 instead of 20116 as year

Comment: Or maybe 2011.  You never know :)

Comment: Yea :) That's where his issue is anyway